# Change position HTML element in Drupal 6

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-theming

I'm currently implementing accessibility website to meet the Level AA Conformance

One of the things that I do not meet the correct labeling of the elements on the forms.

Currently my HTML structure is this:

```
<label for="edit-title">Text</label>
<div class="views-widget">
     <div class="form-item" id="edit-title-wrapper">
          <input type="text" id="edit-title" size="30" value="" class="form-text">
     </div>
</div>
```

I would change the structure to this other.

```
<div class="views-widget">
     <div class="form-item" id="edit-title-wrapper">
          <label for="edit-title">Text</label>
          <input type="text" id="edit-title" size="30" value="" class="form-text">
     </div>
</div>
```

Order to have the "input" tag after the label tag.

My question is if there is any possible way to make this change easily in Drupal.

Thanks.

Best Regards.

Comment: are you implementing this in a custom module mate..??

Comment: I've researched, use form_alter_hook, I'll find examples of how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can edit template archive .tpl or create one in theme options in views module. In this template you can add and modify elements.